# Is all data sent over SSH encrypted?

Tags: encryption, ssh

When you are connected to another computer over SSH, is all data transferred between the two computers encrypted? Or is any data sent in plaintext or any other "easy to intercept" format?

Comment: Note: Look up the [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) method for an example that builds a shared secret upon a non-secured channel in the presence of an eavesdropper.

Comment: No. - The public keys that are established are not encrypted. This is intentional and isn't a security risk.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For any protocol, you could come up with a definition of "all data" that would necessarily imply that *something* isn't sent encrypted.

For example, during the initialization and key exchange, the algorithm selection is public. Your average cryptographer will give you little more than a raised eyebrow if you complain about that fact though, since obviously it *can't* be encrypted as you haven't selected an algorithm yet.

Obviously *something* has to be sent unencrypted if for no other purpose than to set up encryption. But once the connection is secure, *everything* is secure. Once you have an encrypted channel, nothing from that point on is sent outside that channel. Furthermore, the protocol is extremely cautious to avoid sending any *sensitive* data before encryption is available. No username, no password, no identification of any sort, no indication of purpose, or any of that.

What little there is to decode is readily decode-able using common free tools such as wireshark. Fire up a packet capture, start an SSH session, and examine the exchange yourself. You'll see immediately what can be seen and what can't. Wireshark does a great job at decoding the protocol to allow you to view the internals of how it works.... to the extent that it's visible to someone watching the network traffic.

The typical flow looks like this:

1. SSH version/software identification
2. Key exchange init (algorithm selection)
3. Diffie-Hellman key exchange (uses SSH host key to prevent MITM)
   *Everything after this is encrypted*
4. User authentication (including user key-based authentication)
5. SSH Session now activate

Comment: What if a password is used for authentication instead of logging in with a public key?

Comment: @IQAndreas the encrypted session is set up before any authentication is attempted.

Comment: @IQAndreas: Your login key is not the same as the server's SSH key. No matter how you login, the SSH session has already been established.

Comment: I think that point should be added to the answer.

Comment: @tylerl Actually the public key of the server is encrypted. That's not because the public key needs to be kept secret, but rather because the SSH protocol is designed to negotiate a session key and enable encryption, before it does anything else.

Comment: @kasperd: that's incorrect; server auth and kx are in the same message(s) which are clear on a normal/initial handshake -- see e.g. rfc4253 section 8. (If you _reexchange_ on a _preexisting_ session, aka rekey, _all_ of _that_ is encrypted; section 9.) _Client_ auth (if any) is after NEWKEYS and is encrypted.